# Javascript assign variable if nil?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Is there some shorthand in Javascript to assign a variable if it evaluates to false?

In ruby I can do this:

```
foo |= "bar"
```

Assigns "bar" to foo if foo evaluates to false
so something like this: (using that |= operator)

```
var cars_by_brand_and_color = {};
for (var car in parking_lot) {
   // add a brand if it doesn't exist yet;
   // cars_by_brand_and_color['chevrolet'] = {};
   cars_by_brand_and_color[car['brand']] |= {};
   // and add that color to the brand if it doesn't exist yet;
   // cars_by_brand_and_color['chevrolet']['grey'] |= {}; 
   cars_by_brand_and_color[car['brand']][car['color']] |= {};
   // now let's add that car; 
   // cars_by_brand_and_color['chevrolet']['grey']['BDB-565'] = 'Mr. Smith';
   cars_by_brand_and_color[car['brand']][car['color']][car['lisence_plate']] = car['owner']
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, the JS syntax is

```
var toAssign = mayBeNull || {};
```

Comment: I knew that. But there's no shorthand? But now i have to type out the varname twice. Bad for readability if these are very long. (see example)

Comment: No, unfortunately there's no shorthand assignment operator corresponding to `||` whose short-circuit-evaluation properties are leveraged when doing this.

Comment: Or is there a way to assign this: cars_by_brand_and_color[car['brand']][car['color']][car['lisence_plate']] = car['owner']; Directly, and force the creating of all the 'associative layers' if they don't exist yet? Else I just have to deal with it and start copy-pasting... not so DRY (on line level that is...)

Comment: No, at least I can't think of any way which would avoid referencing back up to the "parent" object.